# Is US pre-clearance avaiable for Ethiopian Airlines at Dublin Airport?

Tags: lax, pre-clearance, dub, addis-ababa, ethiopian-airlines

I will be travelling to Los Angeles in a few weeks using Ethiopian airlines and would like to know whether I can avail of the pre-clearance service.

The answers I've gotten so far are confusing as people aren't sure. Most of them say no because pre-clearance is only available in Terminal 2 and EA departs from Terminal 1. Also since the flight's original journey begins at ADD and not DUB, passengers would have to go off the plane, pick their baggage, go through terminal 2 and do it since all passengers must use the pre-clearance service.

However other's say that these problems are sorted out and it is indeed available. What is correct?

Comment: The flight is scheduled to arrive in Dublin at 05:40 and leave at 06:50. Even if parked at a preclearance gate, it doesn't sound realistic to tip out a 787's worth of passengers and get them all herded through preclearance and boarded again in just 70 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dublin Airport web information](https://www.dublinairport.com/flight-information/airlines-terminal-2), the airlines which fly from Terminal 2 are Aer Lingus, American Airlines, Delta, Emirates, and United. Your onward flight to the US would have to be with one of those carriers to take advantage of its pre-clearance services.

> [**US Preclearance at Dublin Airport**](https://www.dublinairport.com/at-the-airport/passenger-information/us-preclearance-facility)
>
> The US Preclearance (USCBP) facility at Terminal 2 in Dublin Airport is a purpose built facility that allows US bound passengers to undertake all US immigration, customs and agriculture inspections at Dublin Airport prior to departure.
>
> Dublin Airport is one of only a handful of airports outside North America that offers a US Preclearance facility. The benefit is that having cleared USCBP, passengers arriving in the US are treated as domestic arrivals, allowing them to avoid immigration queues upon arrival and pick up their bags and go.
>
> In addition, this benefits onward connecting passengers in the US who will have their baggage checked through to their final destination.